# Big insert / import

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I'm starting to explore OrientDB with php.

I need to insert 500.000 records into the database, as the record count increases when inserting the insert performance drops significantly. I've been reading you can use "OIntentMassiveInsert" with JAVA, which does not exist within the PHP SDK.

How can I improve the import performance?